# Displaying physical block devices

Tags: fedora, block-device, lsblk

I need to list all block devices installed in my system. There is a command named `lsblk` to show all block devices.

```
[kni@hist ttyid:0 pią kwi 13 17:56:26 ~]$ lsblk 
NAME                   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                      8:0    0   16G  0 disk 
├─sda1                   8:1    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─sda2                   8:2    0 13,5G  0 part 
  ├─fedora_211829-root 253:0    0   10G  0 lvm  /
  ├─fedora_211829-swap 253:1    0  1,5G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─fedora_211829-home 253:2    0    2G  0 lvm  /home
sr0                     11:0    1 55,3M  0 rom  /run/media/kni/VBox_GAs_5.2
[knis@hist ttyid:0 pią kwi 13 17:56:31 ~]$
```

This is the resault of `lsblk` command executed in my system. Is the  `sda` disk the only one physical device in my system? Partitions and lvm are logical parts of the disk. Am I right?

Is there other way to print physical block devices?

Comment: `sda` and `sr0` are the only _physical_ block devices; `sda1` and `sda2` are indeed block devices, but they are logical and not physical.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you actually want to see *physical* devices, and not just all block devices:

My recommendation will then be:

```
lsblk -a -d -e 230
```

Why?

Let us review what these command line options do, from the man page:

```
       -a, --all
              Also list empty devices.  (By default they are skipped.)
```

Strangely, `lsblk` shows my laptop's DVD burner even when it is empty, without `-a`. But it doesn't seem to hurt anything to leave it present.

```
       -d, --nodeps
              Do not print holder  devices  or  slaves.   For  example,  lsblk
              --nodeps /dev/sda prints information about the sda device only.
```

This means we don't see partitions on a device, just the device itself.

```
       -e, --exclude list
              Exclude  the  devices  specified  by the comma-separated list of
              major  device  numbers.   Note  that  RAM  disks  (major=1)  are
              excluded  by  default.   The  filter is applied to the top-level
              devices only.
```

Finally, I use `-e 230` to exclude ZFS zvols, which use this major number. They are entirely logical block devices, but the ZFS driver makes them appear in `lsblk` the same as physical disk devices. If you use ZFS, you can exclude zvols from display with `-e 230`.

```
[root@dalaran ~]# lsblk -a -d -e 230
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda       8:0    0 894.3G  0 disk 
sr0      11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
nvme0n1 259:0    0   477G  0 disk
```

I do *not* recommend using `-S` option, as this will cause NVMe devices to not be displayed.

---

There are several other options in the `lsblk` man page which allow for making the output more machine readable, in case you want to write a shell script. For instance `-n` and `-o` or `-P`.

Comment: Strictly speaking, NVMe devices are not physical block devices. The kernel provides a translation layer on top of the NVMe interface that lets you use it as a block device, but as far as the kernel is concerned, it is not natively a block device.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn If you put it in those terms, one could say the same thing about SATA or SCSI. And I'm sure I would be surprised to find out that my SSD doesn't have any physical existence.

Comment: Except thet the low level kernel interface doesn't treat NVMe devices like block devices, but it does treat SCSI (which may not be block devices) and SATA (which actually has a block device style interface at the protocol level) as block devices all the way down to the protocol drivers.

Comment: The `-d` option is not working for me, as I still see several EMMC devices (mmcblk0, mmcblk0boot0, mmcblk0boot1, mmcblk0rpmb) while I'm pretty sure there is only one physical device on biard.

Answer (score 1):

Get info (without partitions):

```
$ lsblk -a -d
NAME MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda    8:0    0   20G  0 disk
sdb    8:16   0   40G  0 disk
sr0   11:0    1 55.3M  0 rom

-a       print even empty devices (if disk is not loaded in CD/DVD device)
-d       discard print slaves
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -l /sys/block/ | awk '$11 != "" && $11 !~ "^../devices/virtual" { print $9; }
```